# Связанная запись в CGridView в Yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

Здравствуйте. Сгенерировал CGridView через gii. Есть профиль водителя, у него есть статус (занят, свободен, болен и пр.), связан с таблицей по полю id_status. Модели обеих таблиц связаны. А как сделать, чтоб грид выводил не id_status, а name (имя статуса) из связанной таблицы?

Код грида:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'driver-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'phone',
    'photo',
    'id_status',// $model->DriverStatus->name ???
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Получение имени статуса если что: `$model->DriverStatus->name`

Comment: было вроде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто и явно! Ведь это же Yii!

```
'columns'=>array(
'id',
'name',
'phone',
'photo',
'DriverStatus.name', //!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

а разве не так?

```
'value' => '($data->id_status)? $data->DriverStatus->name : ""',
```